# Selecting object in 2 dimensional arrays js

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a 2 dimensional array (I'll call it `myArray`). `myArray` is full of 10 child arrays, each with 10 "-"s.

```
function mapInit () {
    max_size = 10;
    board = [];

    map_width = Math.floor((Math.random() * max_size + max_size) / 2);
    map_height = Math.floor((Math.random() * max_size + max_size) / 2);

    boardsize = { x : map_width, y : map_height }
}

function generateBoard () {
    var columns = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < map_height; i++) {
        columns.push("---");
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < map_width; i++) {
        board.push(columns);
    };
}
```

When I select `myArray[x][y]`, it returns the value of the single object in that array: "-". This makes sense because I asked for that individual value.

When I set `myArray[x][y] = 1`, it sets all [y] in the second-level arrays to 1. It should set the individual value in that specific child array to 1, because the individual value is what was just returned when I selected `myArray[x][y]`. What am I doing wrong / not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong / not understanding?

You adding a reference to a single array multiple times to another array. Take a look at this simplified example:

```
var a = [];
var b = [a, a];

a[0] = 42;
console.log(b);
// [[42], [42]]
```

as you can see, I'm setting `a` as the first and second element in the `b` array. There is no reason why this operation should create two copies of `a` in the process. Both elements reference the same array, which you can easily test with

```
b[0] === b[1] // true
```

Two distinct arrays would never be equal to each other (`[] === []` returns `false`).

---

**Solution:** [Create a copy of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7486085/218196) inside the second loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < map_width; i++) {
    board.push(columns.slice(0));
}
```